# WooCommerce API w/ Client Lib: How to retrieve custom product fields outside the WP loop

Tags: wordpress, api, woocommerce, product, client-library

I'm using WP WooCommerce and I want to add custom product fields that shall be used in conjunction with the [API Client Lib](https://github.com/kloon/WooCommerce-REST-API-Client-Library).

I followed [this guide](http://www.remicorson.com/mastering-woocommerce-products-custom-fields/) to the end and everything works fine, except for reading the data. Now, I'm using the API Client Library for processing the orders where I want to fetch this meta information of the products. But how to I access this information? Since my script does not run within the WP loop, I can't access any get_post_meta function or the like. It is also not listed in the product meta, I get from the API (and I don't understand why).

The only solution I see right now is to get the data directly from the wp_postmeta table in MySQL.  Is this correct or is there any other, more elegant, way to get this data?

Thx for any help.

*Edit:* I use workaround for this problem now. Since there is seemingly no way to access the product meta data outside of the loop, I now use **WP's native custom fields** to retrieve that data. In contrary to the WC product meta data the WP custom field can be accessed via the WC API. The data sits in the **parent** of my product, so I can access it by making a second API call for the parent.